# Отключить отображение для мобильных устройств

Tags: html, css3, вёрстка, menu

Сделал меню для сайта вот по этому примеру

https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Touch-Swipeable-Sidebar-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3.html

выделил css стили в @media screen and (min-width: 320px) {}

но при проверке на обычном экране (не мобильного устройства) это меню никуда не убирается.

Как цель - убрать все стили и поставить другие для большого экрана (сделать меню горизонтальным вместо бокового.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 600px) {}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, совсем забыл ограничить max